# how to globally used parsed values in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, global-variables

```
func jsonParsing1(){
           do{
            let path : NSString =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "json")!
            let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            let jsonArray = jsonData
           ** let templeArray = (jsonArray.valueForKey("temple-name") as? NSArray)!**

           }catch {
           print(error)


        }
    }
}
```

my json files is 
[
    {
        “temple-name”: "aaa",
        “image”: "image.png”,
        “description”: “aaa“
    },
        {
        “temple-name”: "bbb",
        “image”: "image1.png”,
        “description”: “bbb“
    }
]
I am using json file in a separate class and trying to access the parsed array all through the project.
Used global array but it returns nil when calling from another class. Thanks in advance.

I need to use the templeArray globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton class with templeArray property, store the value in this array and access it through shared instance of the singleton class.
Or,

You can declare templeArray property in appDelegate and global access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `static` variables to access data across your project.

```
class GlobalVariables {
    static var templeArray : NSMutableArray?
}
```

You can use `templeArray` throughout your application via

```
GlobalVariables.templeArray?.objectAtIndex(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this kind of approach:

```
class MyClass {

static var templeArray : NSArray?


     func jsonParsing1(){
        let path : NSString =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "json")!
        let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        let jsonArray = jsonData
        MyClass.templeArray = (jsonArray.valueForKey("temple-name") as? NSArray)!

        /*
         * You can now access to templeArray in this way:
         * let myArray : NSArray? = MyClass.templeArray
         */
     }
}
```

In addition, the do/catch block is useless in Swift2.

EDIT: 
You are doing it wrong.

```
let templeArray = (jsonArray.valueForKey("temple-name") as? NSArray)!
```

will always be nil because the field temple name isn't an array, it is a string.
You have to do:

```
MyClass.templeArray = jsonArray
```

Then you can access the first temple this way:

```
let temple = MyClass.templeArray[0]
let templeName : String = temple.objectForKey("temple-name") as? String
```

Comment: That's because you are performing a conditional downcast, so are you sure you have data in your json?

Comment: yes, when I print the templeArray withing jsonParsing() it prints the values. But outside the function, it shows nil.

Comment: Can you please give a snippet to see how are you accessing the array?

Comment: As shown, class ListView: UITableViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        templeRows = MyClass.templeArray
    }

Comment: please update your initial post with a json example, the points when json is parsed and the point when the array is accessed.

Comment: I have given a sample json file with the code where array is accessed... any solutions...

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
var templeArray: NSMutableArray = []

class Parser {

    func jsonParsing1() {
        do {
            let path : NSString =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "json")!
            let data : NSData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            let jsonArray = jsonData
            if let rawTempleArray = jsonArray.valueForKey("temple-name") as? NSMutableArray {
                templeArray = rawTempleArray
            } else {
                print("temple-name is not array")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I would do like this:

```
struct Temple { //or class
    // your fields here
    init? (templeDictionary: NSDictionary) {
        // your parser here
    }
}


class TheParser {
    static var theTempleArray: [Temple] = []

    func jsonParsing1() {
        do {
            let path : NSString =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "json")!
            let data : NSData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            let jsonArray = jsonData
            if let rawTempleArray = jsonArray.valueForKey("temple-name") as? NSArray {
                for temple in rawTempleArray {
                    if let theTemple = temple as? NSDictionary { // or NSArray or String depending of your json structure
                        if let templeItem = Temple(templeDictionary: theTemple) {
                            TheParser.theTempleArray.append(templeItem)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("temple-name is not array")
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)

        }
    }

}
```